# $i doesnt work within the for-loop in an awk statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, awk

PFB the code:

```
for i in 3 4 5 6 7;
do
echo "try $i";
cat vm.txt | cut -f6 -d" " | awk '{ if (NR==$i) print $0 }';
sleep 1;
done;
```

The file vm.txt contains:

```
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr s0 s1 s2 s3   in   sy   cs us sy id
 1 0 0 108257664 49651668 401 2616 445 0 0 0 1 3 -0 6 6 1436 13883 1427 1 47 52
 0 0 0 100580908 40823736 1533 4406 4075 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3190 99090 2767 10 2 88
 1 0 0 100580720 40771708 917 5865 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0 3747 137273 3557 13 2 85
 1 0 0 100580168 40721008 401 1725 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0 3220 109486 2761 11 2 87
 1 0 0 100581152 40703900 199 2494 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0 3727 91301 2932 9  2 89
 1 0 0 100581636 40710604 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 2472 59069 2136 8  1 91
 1 0 0 100581644 40730952 45 501 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 2939 87167 2540 9  1 90
 2 0 0 100581632 40712628 46 502 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 3251 88502 2763 9  1 90
 1 0 0 100581628 40757704 185 219 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0 3058 81429 2590 9  1 90
 1 0 0 100581628 40747620 3602 52322 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7353 127233 6077 10 5 85
```

Now when i run this command:

```
cat vm.txt | cut -f6 -d" " | awk '{ if (NR==3) print $0 }';
```

It works, but it doesnt work in the for-loop. I dont know what the issue is. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please note that the `;` chars. at the end of your commands are superfluous; generally, you only need `;` between commands to place *multiple* on the *same* line.

Comment: One suggestion which not related the problem. The for loop with continuous input number can be updated to :`for i in {3..7}; do echo $i; done` , so you needn't type the number list one by one, for example if more than 100 :). Secondly, your code is not good at all, need read the source file many times. You should refer @Ed Morton 's awk script, which only read one time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument to `awk` is in single quotes, and shell variables are not interpolated in single quotes.  You could change the quotes to double (and then escape any dollar signs that really do need to get through to `awk`):

```
for i in 3 4 5 6 7; do
  echo "try $i"
  cat vm.txt | cut -f6 -d" " | awk "{ if (NR==$i) print \$0 }"
  sleep 1
done
```

Or alternatively, it may be more robust to stick with single quotes but assign the shell variable to an Awk variable (it makes no difference in this specific example but in general, if `$i` might contain spaces, etc...):

```
for i in 3 4 5 6 7; do
  echo "try $i"
  cat vm.txt | cut -f6 -d" " | awk -v ndx="$i" '{ if (NR==ndx) print $0 }'
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Brilliant, this did the trick. I was trying to escape the dollar sign at first but didn't really that awk wa in single quotes. Much appreciated. :) Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely do NOT do the first approach suggested above using double quotes as it totally unnecessarily complicates your awk script by introducing the need to escape `$` signs and there's probably other caveats. The second approach has issues too. I'll post something once I get a second to look at the question.

Comment: @EdMorton: The 2nd approach only has one issue: `index` is the name of an `awk` *function* and can therefore not be used as a variable name; something like `ndx` would be fine. On a stylistic note, the *option* form of setting the variable - e.g. `-v ndx="$i"` - *before* the program, probably makes the intent clearer.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the pointers, I've updated the answer to take them into account.

Comment: @mklement0 no, there are several issues, including a UUOC, unnecessary `cut`, and mis-using the awk syntax by puting the condition inside the action part and then hard-coding the default action.

Comment: @EdMorton: *This* answer resolves the OP's immediate problem, making the difference between non-functioning and functioning - however inefficient; *your* answer goes much further in optimizing the approach. As such, your answer *complements* this one, and *both* have value. If your answer were the only one, the OP's confusion about `$` in the shell context vs `$` in `awk`'s context would never be cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to print the 5th field for lines 3 4 5 6 7. That'd be:

```
$ awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=7{print $5}' vm.txt
49651668
40823736
40771708
40721008
40703900
```

If you want something different, update your question to clarify.

Comment: +1 for a great improvement on the original approach (though it won't help the OP understand his problem).